# How to use groupby and filter data frame to create a new column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Say I have a dataset which contains time series of the heart rates of patients who stay in an ICU.

I would like to add some inclusion criteria, for example I would only like to consider the ICU stays of patients whose heart rate was >= 90 for at least one hour. If the heart rate at the first measurement after one hour (beginning at the >=90 value) is unknown, we assume it's above 90 and include that ICU stay.

The entries of that ICU stay should be included starting from the first measurement corresponding to the ”at least 1 hour” timespan.

Note that once the ICU stay is included, it never gets exlcuded again, even if the heart rate goes back down below 90 at some point.

So the dataframe below, where "Icustay" corresponds to the unique ID of a stay in the ICU and "Hours" indicates the time spent in the ICU since entry

```
   Heart Rate  Hours  Icustay  Inclusion Criteria
0          79    0.0     1001                   0
1          91    1.5     1001                   0
2         NaN    2.7     1001                   0
3          85    3.4     1001                   0
4          90    0.0     2010                   0
5          94   29.4     2010                   0
6          68    0.0     3005                   0
```

Should become

```
   Heart Rate  Hours  Icustay  Inclusion Criteria
0          79    0.0     1001                   0
1          91    1.5     1001                   1
2         NaN    2.7     1001                   1
3          85    3.4     1001                   1
4          90    0.0     2010                   1
5          94   29.4     2010                   1
6          68    0.0     3005                   0
```

I have written code for this, and it works. However it is pretty slow, it can take up to a few seconds per patient when working with my entire dataset (in reality my dataset contains more data than just there 6 fields, but I have simplified it for better readability). Since there are 40'000 patients, I would like to speed this up.

This is the code I'm currently using, along with the toy dataset I have presented above.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'Icustay': [1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 2010, 2010, 3005], 'Hours': [0, 1.5, 2.7, 3.4, 0, 29.4, 0],
     'Heart Rate': [79, 91, np.NaN, 85, 90, 94, 68], 'Inclusion Criteria':[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
all_records = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


for curr in np.unique(all_records['Icustay']):
    print(curr)
    curr_stay = all_records[all_records['Icustay']==curr]
    indexes = curr_stay['Hours'].index
    heart_rate_flag = False
    heart_rate_begin_time = 0
    heart_rate_begin_index = 0
    for i in indexes:
        if(curr_stay['Heart Rate'][i] >= 90 and not heart_rate_flag):
            heart_rate_flag = True
            heart_rate_begin_time = curr_stay['Hours'][i]
            heart_rate_begin_index = i
        elif(curr_stay['Heart Rate'][i] < 90):
            heart_rate_flag = False
        elif(heart_rate_flag and curr_stay['Hours'][i]-heart_rate_begin_time >= 1.0):
            all_records['Inclusion Criteria'].iloc[indexes[indexes>=heart_rate_begin_index]] = 1
            break
```

Note that the dataset is ordered by patient and hours.

Is there a way to speed this up? I have thought about built in functions like group by, but I'm not sure they would help in this particular case.

Comment: Thanks for a thorough question.  What should happen if a heart rate goes back below 90 during the same ICU stay?

Comment: the inclusion criteria stays 1 for the rest of the patient's stay if s/he satisfied the criteria at some point, even if the heart rate goes back down below 90.

I'll edit my question to make that clearer

Comment: I'm a little confused about the timespans.  You say: `The entries of that ICU stay should be included starting from the first measurement corresponding to the ”at least 1 hour” timespan.`, but in your example you include the first observation for ICU stay `2010`, even though that is observed at Hours = `0.0`.

Comment: The "at least 1 hour" was referring to the timespan of the inclusion criteria, not the overal ICU stay. So for ICU stay 2010, the heart rate was higher than 90 for a period of at least one hour, that period began at time 0.0 which is why it's included

Comment: @Skum - I see that you've accepted my answer, but I think I may have misunderstood your criteria and just got lucky that I ended up with the same results as you. Please let me know if after testing on a bigger dataset it doesn't yield the expected results and I'm sure I'll be able to edit it appropriately.

Comment: I've just tested it on the whole dataset and indeed it's not quite correct. https://imgur.com/BfPvZJH In this pic I've marked the correctly labelled entries with a check and the wrong ones with an x. NaNs shouldn't be assumed to be 90 unless it's the first value you meet one hour after the value above 90 that began the "window" for the inclusion criteria. Sorry if this is a bit confusing, it's a very specific problem so it's hard to both explain it correctly and be brief.

Comment: @Skum - I have given this another go - see updated answer. I'm not 100% confident that it'll catch every edge case but please give it a try. If it fails, can you please provide some data which causes it to fail.

Comment: I've been going through the data to look for wrong scenarios, but it seems like it always worked as intended, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will look a bit ugly but it avoids loops, and `apply` (which is essentially just a loop under the hood). I haven't tested on a large dataset but I suspect it will be a lot faster than your current code.

First, create some additional columns which contain details of the next/previous lines, since this can be relevant for some of your conditions:

```
all_records['PrevHeartRate'] = all_records['Heart Rate'].shift()
all_records['NextHours'] = all_records['Hours'].shift(-1)
all_records['PrevICU'] = all_records['Icustay'].shift()
all_records['NextICU'] = all_records['Icustay'].shift(-1)
```

Next, create a DataFrame containing the first qualifying record per id (this is now very messy due to the amount of logic involved):

```
first_per_id = (all_records[((all_records['Heart Rate'] >= 90) |
                            ((all_records['Heart Rate'].isnull()) & 
                            (all_records['PrevHeartRate'] >= 90) &
                            (all_records['Icustay'] == all_records['PrevICU']))) &
                            ((all_records['Hours'] >= 1) |
                            ((all_records['NextHours'] >= 1) &
                            (all_records['NextICU'] == all_records['Icustay'])))]
                .drop_duplicates(subset='Icustay', keep='first')[['Icustay']]
                .reset_index()
                .rename(columns={'index': 'first_index'}))
```

This gives us:

```
   first_index  Icustay
0            1     1001
1            4     2010
```

You can drop all the new columns from the original DataFrame now:

```
all_records.drop(['PrevHeartRate', 'NextHours', 'PrevICU', 'NextICU'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

We can then merge this with the original DataFrame:

```
new = pd.merge(all_records, first_per_id, how='left', on='Icustay')
```

Giving:

```
   Heart Rate  Hours  Icustay  Inclusion Criteria  first_index
0        79.0    0.0     1001                   0          1.0
1        91.0    1.5     1001                   0          1.0
2        97.0    2.7     1001                   0          1.0
3         NaN    3.4     1001                   0          1.0
4        90.0    0.0     2010                   0          4.0
5        94.0   29.4     2010                   0          4.0
6        68.0    0.0     3005                   0          NaN
```

From here we can compare 'first_index' (which is the first qualifying index for that id), to the actual index:

```
new['Inclusion Criteria'] = new.index >= new['first_index']
```

This gives:

```
       Heart Rate  Hours  Icustay  Inclusion Criteria  first_index
0        79.0    0.0     1001               False          1.0
1        91.0    1.5     1001                True          1.0
2        97.0    2.7     1001                True          1.0
3         NaN    3.4     1001                True          1.0
4        90.0    0.0     2010                True          4.0
5        94.0   29.4     2010                True          4.0
6        68.0    0.0     3005               False          NaN
```

From here, we just need to tidy up (convert results column to integer, and delete first_index column):

```
new.drop('first_index', axis=1, inplace=True)
new['Inclusion Criteria'] = new['Inclusion Criteria'].astype(int)
```

Giving the final desired results:

```
       Heart Rate  Hours  Icustay  Inclusion Criteria
0        79.0    0.0     1001                   0
1        91.0    1.5     1001                   1
2        97.0    2.7     1001                   1
3         NaN    3.4     1001                   1
4        90.0    0.0     2010                   1
5        94.0   29.4     2010                   1
6        68.0    0.0     3005                   0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` and `apply` function in pandas. This should be faster also.

```
## fill missing values 
all_records['Heart Rate'].fillna(90, inplace=True)

## use apply
all_records['Inclusion Criteria'] = all_records.groupby('Icustay').apply(lambda x: (x['Heart Rate'].ge(90)) & (x['Hours'].ge(0))).values.astype(int)

print(all_records)

   Heart Rate  Hours  Icustay  Inclusion Criteria
0        79.0    0.0     1001                   0
1        91.0    1.5     1001                   1
2        97.0    2.7     1001                   1
3        90.0    3.4     1001                   1
4        90.0    0.0     2010                   1
5        94.0   29.4     2010                   1
6        68.0    0.0     3005                   0
```

Comment: Thanks, sadly this doesn't solve the problem (that I just edited to make the problem clear), as it excludes the heart rates below 90 after the ICU stay has satisfied the inclusion criteria. Sorry for not making that clearer in the original question